# Why does System.Windows.MessageBox lag a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, messagebox

Consider the following code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("MyMessage");
}
```

If I am trying to display a message box after a WPF window has been loaded, when I run the application, the WPF window is displayed with a transparent background (only the non-client area is visible) and it takes 3-5 seconds until the message box appears. The WPF window returns to normal only after the message box has been closed.

Is this normal? Does anyone else experience this?

**EDIT: I have added a screenshot of how the window looks like:**

[image]

Comment: Which MessageBox are you using?

Comment: @Bob. `System.Windows.MessageBox` per the question title. Someone actually posted a (now deleted) answer to be sure to make sure you're using `System.Windows` and not `System.Windows.Forms` since `System.Windows.Forms` pulls several dlls that WPF normally doesn't need, and OP verified that they're using `System.Windows.MessageBox`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `MessageBox` is getting shown at the `Normal` [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), which occurs before things like `DataBind`, `Render`, and `Loaded`, so the code that initializes your Window's objects is not getting run until after you dismiss the `MessageBox`

You can fix this by simply showing the `MessageBox` at a later DispatcherPriority, such as `Background`

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, 
        new Action(delegate() { MessageBox.Show("MyMessage"); }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598678.aspx) overload of `Show` method, or any other overload, accepting `Window` instance as parameter.